# Rightly save data to the mongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, mongodb

Have an application in Angular. Don't understand how to do rightly save data.

This is part of my api:

```
.post('/type/add', function(req, res){
   var type = new NewType({
      type: req.body.type,
      subtype: req.body.subtype,
   });
   type.save(function(err, newTypeOne){
      if(err){
         res.send(err);
         return;
      }
      res.json({message: "New type Created!"});
   });
})
```

This is my mongodb schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var Type = new Schema({
    type: String,
    subtype: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('NewType', Type);
```

This is my controller:

```
.controller('AddTypeController', ['CreateType', 'AllType', '$location', function(CreateType, AllType, $location){
   vm = this;
   vm.createType = function(){
     vm.message = '';
     CreateType.create(vm.typeData)
       .success(function(data){
       vm.typeData = '';
       vm.message = data.message;
       $location.path('/type')
       });
   };
   AllType.getAll().success(function(data){
      vm.types = data;
   });
}])
```

And this is my service:

```
angular.module('typeService', [])
.factory('AllType', function($http){
   var typeFactory = {};
   typeFactory.getAll = function(){
      return $http.get('/api/type');
   };
   return typeFactory;

})
.factory('CreateType', function($http){
   var typeFactory = {};
   typeFactory.create = function(typeData){
      return $http.post('/api/type/add', typeData);
   };
   return typeFactory;
})
```

My HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="AddTypeController as type">
<form>
   <md-select ng-model="type.typeData.type" placeholder="Type">
      <md-option ng-value="typeone.type" ng-repeat="typeone in type.types">{{typeone.type}}</md-option>
   </md-select>
   <md-input-container flex>
      <label>SubTyp</label>
      <input ng-model="type.typeData.subtype">
   </md-input-container>
   <button ng-click="type.createType()">Send</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Now i have a problem:
for example i don't have data yet. I adding in first select - TypeOne, and in second select - SubTypeOne. in database now i have {type: TypeOne, subtype: SubTypeOne}. When i adding second subType to TypeOne, i selecting in first select TypeOne and adding subtype in input - SubTypeTwo. now i have second record in database {type: TypeOne, subtype: SubTypeTwo}, and after this in first select i have TypeOne two times.

But i want to do something like this: if i already have needed type, and want to add only new subtype. In this case i want to have in the database smth like this: {type: TypeOne, subtype:[subtype: SubTypeOne, subtype: SubTypeTwo]}. For this i ought to save subtype like an array, but don't understand how.

Answer (score 0):

In your model you should have the subtypes as an array of strings.  Then you can push them onto that array.  An example is shown below:

```
var Type = new Schema({
    type: String,
    subtype: [String]
});
```

Then you can have an update method (mongoose: findOneAndUpdate) instead of just creating a new Type.  Or you can have it check for if it can find one, and update that, otherwise create a new one.  An example is shown below:

```
CreateType.findOneAndUpdate({type: 'type1'},
    {$push: {subtype: 'type2'} },
    function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        // Do the create for a new one here
    else
        // Send back a 200 OK or whatever else
});
```

This will allow you to update the array as they are.  I encourage you to look into the [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) documentation on mongoose, as well as the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) mongo documentation.

Hope this helps!  I've been working on an app lately that is basically doing what I've described here.  So I've actually been using this to attest that it works.

Comment: Thank you. I'm doing something like this, but doesn't work. Always have else.... 
Type.findOneAndUpdate({type: req.body.type}, {$push: {subtype: req.body.subtype}}, function(err, type){
                if(err){
                    type.save(function(err, newType){
                    if(err){
                        res.send(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    res.json({message: "Created!"});
                });
                }
                else{
                   res.json({message: req.body.type});
                }
            })

Comment: I don't think you should need the type.save() if you are using findOneAndUpdate (as I didn't need it).